# Specify request parameters in dotnetopenauth 4

Tags: facebook, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I need to get Facebook display a "Log in to Facebook" prompt rather than a "Go to App" action when performing OAuth. In order to do this, I need to specify "display=popup" as part of the request.

How can I do this when performing OAuth with DotNetOpenAuth 4 using their WebServerClient object?

It seems in previous versions there was a requestParameters parameter in PrepareRequestUserAuthorization but now it just takes an IEnumerable listing scopes.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `display=popup` query parameter to the URL you set on `AuthorizationServerDescription.AuthorizationEndpoint`.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me for facebook. @Andrew-Arnott, To implement similar popup UI for google login, how to pass "ltmpl=popup" in query string.