# Smaller Google login window with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I'm using GoogleOpenIdClient in DotNetOpenAuth for authentication. However, if the user is not logged in, I get sent to a huge window, which is suboptimal since we are trying to do authentication in a popup window. How do I modify this so that the login screen is much smaller?

Comment: I wasn't aware that this class uses popups at all. I believe it just uses redirects on your web site's own window. If this is not the case, please elaborate as to how you've changed this behavior for your site.

Comment: Like something we have accomplished using this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797714/specify-request-parameters-in-dotnetopenauth-4