# DotNetOpenAuth OAuth authorization using popup window in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, google-api, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, google-oauth

I need to use a **popup window** for Google OAuth authentication. I am using DotNetOpenAuth library to do the authentication and it is working on same page. How can I do this on popup window. I have look around by googling and I have found few and one of them is " [Specify request parameters in dotnetopenauth 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797714/specify-request-parameters-in-dotnetopenauth-4)" But the way I am using this library I don't know where I can set the popup window.

This is my code.

private string AccessToken
    {
            get { return (string)Session["GoogleAccessToken"]; }
            set { Session["GoogleAccessToken"] = value; }
        }

```
    private static readonly GoogleClient googleClient = new GoogleClient
    {
        ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerKey"],
        ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleConsumerSecret"]),
    }; 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                        
        if (googleClient != null)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var authorization = googleClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();
                if (authorization != null)
                {
                    this.AccessToken = authorization.AccessToken;
                }
                else if (this.AccessToken == null)
                {
                    googleClient.RequestUserAuthorization(scope: new[] { GoogleClient.Scopes.WebMaster.SiteVerification, GoogleClient.Scopes.WebMaster.WebMasterTools });

                }
            }
        } 
    }


private static readonly AuthorizationServerDescription GoogleDescription = new AuthorizationServerDescription {
    TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"),
    AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),   
    ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20,            
};
```

Could you please help me on this (I am new to ASP.Net)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a library that has some support for client-side instrumentation, including opening popup windows as the result of a button click, you might want to look the javascript API:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication